# Extract data Date-wise using Python Code & Save as separate csv Datewise

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to extract data datewise and save as separate csv for each different dates:
"time" is given in this format(2018-03-26T16:09:10.024101278Z) in one column of CSV file.

This Dataset has more than 100k rows taken in a different time. 
"I have tried making a data frame" '''Column name: (name    time id ddr version readings) for reference'''

```
dataset_CT= pd.read_csv("out_1.csv")
dataset_CT['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset_CT['time']).dt.date
dataset_CT['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset_CT['time']).dt.time
dataset_CT.sort_values(by='Dates', axis=0, inplace=True)
dataset_CT.set_index(keys=['Dates'], drop=False,inplace=True)

Date_list=dataset_CT['Dates'].unique().tolist()
```

"got Date_list like this([datetime.date(2018, 3, 26), datetime.date(2018, 3, 31)])"

```
Date_set = dataset_CT.loc[dataset_CT.Dates=='(2018, 3, 26)']
```

I received empty Dataframe like below

```
      name  time id ddr version readings Dates  Time
Dates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How working compare by string?

```
Date_set = dataset_CT.loc[dataset_CT.Dates=='2018-03-26']
```

If not working, try to changed [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
dataset_CT['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset_CT['time']).dt.date
Date_set = dataset_CT.loc[dataset_CT.Dates=='2018-03-26']
```

to [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for datetimes with no times:

```
dataset_CT['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset_CT['time']).dt.floor('d')
Date_set = dataset_CT.loc[dataset_CT.Dates=='2018-03-26']
```

Comment: @anky_91 - It depends of version of pandas, in pandas 0.24.+ boths should working.

Answer (score 1):

As you read your input with default parameters, I will assume that you have comma (`,`) for separator and one header line. IMHO pandas for that is not required here. It is enough to read the file one row at time and write it in a csv file corresponding to the date.

The caveats: add the header to each output csv file and create a new output file for every new date. A `collections.defaultdict` with a custom default function is enough to meet those 2 requirement.

The following code reads an input csv file named `"out_1.csv"` and writes it content in a bunch of files named `out_2018-03-26.csv` the date being the date of all rows in the output file:

```
with open("out_1.csv") as fdin:
    def get_defaults():
        """returns a pair (csv_writer, file_object) for date dat initialized with header"""
        filename = 'out{}.csv'.format(dat)
        fd = open(filename, "w", newline='')
        fd.write(header)
        return (csv.writer(fd), fd)
    outfiles = collections.defaultdict(get_defaults)
    rd = csv.reader(fdin)
    header = next(fdin)             # store the header to later initialize output files
    for row in rd:
        dat = row[1][:10]           # extract the date
        wr = outfiles[dat][0]
        wr.writerow(row)            # and write the row to the appropriate output file
    # close the output files
    for i in outfiles:
        outfile[i][1].close()
```

---

After a second thinking about it, above code could keep too many open files. Here is an improved version that only keep open files for the 3 most recently encountered dates (tested):

```
with open("out_1.csv") as fdin:
    cache = collections.deque()
    seen = set()
    def get_defaults():
        """returns a pair (csv_writer, file_object) for date dat initialized with header"""
        filename = 'out{}.csv'.format(dat)
        fd = open(filename, 'a' if dat in seen else 'w', newline='')
        if 0 == fd.tell():          # file is currently empty: write header
            fd.write(header)
        ret = (csv.writer(fd), fd)
        cache.append(dat)
        seen.add(dat)
        if len(cache) > 3:          # only keep 3 open files
            old = cache.popleft()
            print("Closing", old)
            outfiles[old][1].close()
            del outfiles[old]
        return ret

    outfiles = collections.defaultdict(get_defaults)
    rd = csv.reader(fdin)
    header = next(fdin)   # store the header to later initialize output files
    for row in rd:
        dat = row[1][:10] # extract the date
        wr = outfiles[dat][0]
        wr.writerow(row)  # and write the row to the appropriate output file
    # close the currently opened output files
    for i in outfiles:
        outfiles[i][1].close()
```